# Plotting graph without blocking execution in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot graph inside a while loop, but execution is blocked after **plt.show(G)** command and resumes when i manually kill the plot window.

Code:

```
while True:    
        print G.edges()
        Q = #coming from a function
        if Q > BestQ:
            nx.draw(G)
            plt.show(G)
        if G.number_of_edges() == 0:
            break
```

This is the output of **G.edges()** for two iterations:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 9), (2, 6), (3, 5), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 10)]
[(0, 1), (1, 4), (1, 9), (2, 6), (3, 5), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 10)]
```

How to make this continue after plotting???

Comment: try calling plt.ion() before the while loop.

Comment: try `plt.draw()`, `plt.show()` may not be the best option

Comment: plt.ion() not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `interactive on` and `plt.draw`.
Here you have a working example.
As I do not have your algorithm to generate your G graphs, I will draw constinuously the same network. Anyway, as each call to nx.draw(G) creates a different graph, you can see it updating the plot at each call.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import networkx as nx

plt.ion()   # call interactive on

data = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 9), (2, 6), (3, 5), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 10)]

# I create a networkX graph G
G = nx.Graph()
for item, (a, b) in enumerate(data):
    G.add_node(item)
    G.add_edge(a,b)

# make initial plot and set axes limits.
# (alternatively you may want to set this dynamically)
plot, = plt.plot([], [])
plt.xlim(-1, 3)
plt.ylim(-1, 3)

# here is the plotting stage.
for _ in range(10):           # plot 10 times
    plt.cla()                 # clear the previous plot
    nx.draw(G)
    plt.draw()
    time.sleep(2)             # otherwise it runs to fast to see
```

Comment: plt.draw() is not showing any figure. Any idea why??

Comment: Do you refer to my code ?. The code posted is working perfect with python 2.7 in windows 7. It shows the figure and refresh it 10 times.  Did you copied it **exactly** as it is and got nothing draw? Did you get any error ? If you refer to your own code you should post the minimal executable example that doesnt work in your case.

Comment: I am on linux and using Spyder IDE. It didn't give any error. It just didn't draw anything.

Comment: try it on command line, out from Spyder. I have no linux box here but I will try it in ubuntu this afternoon